# Tunnel Openvpn traffic through ssh?

Tags: openvpn

I know similar question have been asked but none of them are explained thoroughly.
I have setup a VPS and setup openvpn using https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install on tcp and port 443(I have access to limited open ports). Now I want to tunnel the openvpn traffic through ssh.I want to do so because the packets are filtered and any vpn related packets are removed on the network. I'm on a **linux machine**, can anyone explain me how to do so? What changes do I make to **client.ovpn**?

Answer (score 1):

There's actually at least two ways to achieve this:

- Request SSH to forward a local port to your OpenVPN instance, using `ssh -L <local_port>:<remote_host>:<remote_port>`. This feature is described on OpenSSH manpage

> ```
>  -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
>  -L [bind_address:]port:remote_socket
>  -L local_socket:host:hostport
>  -L local_socket:remote_socket
>          Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on the local (client) host are to be forwarded to the given
> ```
>
> host and port, or Unix socket,
>                on the remote side.  This works by allocating a socket to listen to either a TCP port on the local side, optionally bound to the
>   specified bind_address, or
>                to a Unix socket.  Whenever a connection is made to the local port or socket, the connection is forwarded over the secure
>   channel, and a connection is made
>                to either host port hostport, or the Unix socket remote_socket, from the remote machine.

- Request OpenSSH to implement a SOCKS Proxy using `ssh -D <local_port>` and, then, request OpenVPN to use this proxy (using `socks-proxy` configuration directive on your openvpn.conf)

Even if technically similar, the first solution may generate warning/errors because OpenVPN will actually connect to `localhost` instead of the server's real FQDN (which may cause problems with certificate's CommonName attribute).